# I hardlinked to OpenSSL 1.1.1 by mistake. How do I link back to OpenSSL 3.2?

Tags: bash, terminal, openssl, homebrew, macos-monterey

I run MacOS Monterey on an Intel Macbook. My sublime text package control recently stopped working, so I did some searching and someone solved it by linking to OpenSSL's old version with this command:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1o/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

I ran that command, and also this one: `brew link openssl@1.1`

MacOS system default is the newer OpenSSL 3. Using the deprecated version might cause problems in the future, so relinking to the old version was a stupid move :/ I solved my sublime text issue by installing the newest version of Package Control. However, now I'm stuck with this version of OpenSSL.

How do I link back to OpenSSL 3 so that when I run `openssl version`, it shows me openssl 3 again instead of `OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023` ?

I have no idea how to solve this.